# How to convert string into integer pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have dataset with many columns.
I want to take average of each column by grouping them with 'Club'

My data is in the form of string and  some of the data is in the form
'60+2' or '58-1'

I want to convert this string datatype into integer so that i can use them for 
calculating mean.

As i have searched and need re to skip '+ & -'.
.str.split is used to split the string.

In my case pd.to_numeric wil not work as I want to edit bulk column at once

```
    complete_dataset is dataframe

    cols = [i for i in complete_dataset.columns if i not in ['Name','Club', 'Nationality', 'Age', 'Overall', 'Potential', 'Special']]
    for col in cols:
        col = complete_dataset[col] #.str.split('+').astype(int)
        print(col)
        for x in col:
            value = x
            print(value)
    #     df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```

This is giving output as

```
    Name: Acceleration, dtype: object
    89
    92-4
    94
    88-6
    58+2
    79
    70+9
    76
    94
```

Also I want to use this data for further calculations

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. Where is your input? And what do you want the output to be? Do you want to remove the symbols? Do you want to evaluate the expressions? Do you want to extract the integers separately? What is it?

Comment: @COLDSPEED,  I want to remove symbols and add or subtract the numbers as per symbol and convert the string into integer

Comment: What are the "integer pandas" in your question title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to remove symbols and add or subtract the numbers as per symbol
> and convert the string into integer.

### `ast.literal_eval`

Alright, one good way of doing this is using python's safe eval - `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast

df.Acceleration = df.Acceleration.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df

   Acceleration
0            89
1            88
2            94
3            82
4            60
5            79
6            79
7            76
8            94

df.Acceleration.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

`literal_eval` evaluates only certain string expressions. Assuming you have a column of strings with expressions that can be evaluated, this will evaluate them and return numeric results.

Note that if you have a column of mixed integers and strings, the simplest thing to do would be to convert the entire column to string and apply `literal_eval`.

```
df['Acceleration'] = df.Acceleration.astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

---

### `pd.eval`/`df.eval`

Another good way of doing this is using `pandas`' safe eval - `pd.Series.eval`, as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927498/4909087).

```
df.Acceleration = df.eval(df.Acceleration)
df

   Acceleration
0            89
1            88
2            94
3            82
4            60
5            79
6            79
7            76
8            94
```

---

### Handling Malformed Data

On the off chance that your data contains invalid strings, a slightly different solution is needed, because everything mentioned above is going to fail. We'll need to define a function that handles these errors accordingly.

```
def parse(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x) # pd.eval(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df.Acceleration = df.Acceleration.apply(parse)
df

   Acceleration
0            89
1            88
2            94
3            82
4            60
5            79
6            79
7            76
8            94
```

Comment: Is this safe ?`df.Name.apply(lambda x : pd.eval(x))` :-)

Comment: @Wen It is safe. But `pd.eval(df.Name)` is just as safe and faster!

Comment: Aha, :-) got it

Comment: @COLDSPEED , thank you for this answer, It is working for some column only and throwing error as "malformed node or string: 30"

Comment: As i am new to python and pandas, searching for the same

Comment: @akashk It means that some of your strings are invalid expressions. What do you plan to do about it?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, this is working, thanks you again. Please can you suggest me best material to study python.

Comment: Does this address a string that has division or multiplication in it. For ex: `'(20 + 30) / 2'` or `'15 * 3'`

Answer (score 2):

Since your'e using Pandas, I would recommend using `pandas.eval()` instead of Python's `eval()` method as correctly pointed out by Coldspeed (Thanks!).

The advantage of using `pandas.eval()` is that it only evaluates Python expressions and not Python statements, therefore is much safer and compared to the `ast.literal_eval()` method ([link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) should also run a little bit faster .

Concretely, you can amend your code to do the following:

```
import pandas

# Your code to read in the DataFrame goes in here.

complete_dataset['Acceleration'] = pandas.eval(complete_dataset['Acceleration'])
```

This evaluates all expressions that are stored in the column called Acceleration in `df`. The method should perform much faster and the output will the an integer or float depending on the expressions stored in the column.

For more details, please take a look at the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html).

Comment: No! `eval` is a _bad_ idea. Use `ast.literal_eval` instead. See my answer for details.

Comment: If you can remove the first bit of your answer, and elaborate on `df.eval`, you'll have my upvote.

Comment: For example, `df.eval(df.Acceleration)` will also return an answer, and I'm guessing should be faster than my answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments :) I've amended the answer as suggested. In my experience the pandas functions are usually much faster but who knows ;)